# Dialog box not working - Android

Tags: android, dialog, alert, android-alertdialog

I made a refresh item in action bar. When u click it a dialog box will show asking to check the internet connection. The problem is there's no dialog box showing up at all. I wanna know if there's something wrong with my code.

```
private void Refresh() {

    if(IsparkLib.isInternetConnected(InquiryMainActivity.this)){
        nameOfMethod();

        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(InquiryMainActivity.this);
        dialog.setTitle("Are you sure you want to update?");
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(InquiryMainActivity.this,InquiryMainActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
    else{
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(InquiryMainActivity.this);
        dialog.setTitle("Warning");
        dialog.setPositiveButton("OK",null);

        final TextView mes = new TextView(InquiryMainActivity.this);
        mes.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        mes.setText("Please check your internet connection");
        mes.setTextSize(20);


    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You will need to call `AlertDialog.show()` to show alert on screen do it as:

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = dialog.create();
 // show it
alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: thanks its working now but the problem is the Cancel doesn't show up. :/

Comment: @jajaja : what error you are getting please post logcat result with question to get more help

Comment: Thanks I figured it out. it should be setNegativeButton() . Vote up for you! :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are not calling `dialog.show();`. Check once.

In else block try like this...

```
else{
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(InquiryMainActivity.this);
    dialog.setTitle("Warning");
    dialog.setPositiveButton("OK",null);

    final TextView mes = new TextView(InquiryMainActivity.this);
    mes.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    mes.setText("Please check your internet connection");
    mes.setTextSize(20);

    dialog.show();//=> here is the change
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to create the `AlertDialog` instance from `AlertDialog.Builder` object and to show that dialog.

**Another thing**, you have tried to create the  `AlertDialog.Builder` object in both `if-else` condition in `Refresh()` method but you should create outside the `if-else` condition as below...

```
private void Refresh() {

    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(InquiryMainActivity.this);

    if(IsparkLib.isInternetConnected(InquiryMainActivity.this)){
        nameOfMethod();

        dialog.setTitle("Are you sure you want to update?");
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(InquiryMainActivity.this,InquiryMainActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    } else {

        dialog.setTitle("Warning");
        dialog.setPositiveButton("OK",null);

        final TextView mes = new TextView(InquiryMainActivity.this);
        mes.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        mes.setText("Please check your internet connection");
        mes.setTextSize(20);

    }

    AlertDialog alertDialog = dialog.createDialog();
    alertDialog.show();

}
```

**Update:**

For **Cancel** option, you have to add another button to the dialog as below...

```
dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

        //add your code
        dialog.dismiss();

    }
});
```

Comment: thanks its working now but the problem is the Cancel doesn't show up. :/

Comment: For which dialog its not working...`Are you sure you want to update?` or `Warning`?

Comment: I mean I want to show to choices, the Ok and Cancel. It shows in my code.

Comment: Thanks I figured it out. it should be setNegativeButton() . Vote up for you! :)

Comment: Glad to hear it and since your problem is solved then you should close this question be accepting the most appropriate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Add this below two line after `ifelse` condition..

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = dialog.createDialog();
    alertDialog.show();
```

And you complete with your code....

Comment: thanks its working now but the problem is the Cancel doesn't show up. :

Comment: Thanks I figured it out. it should be setNegativeButton() . Vote up for you! :)

Answer (score 1):

edit your code as

```
private void Refresh() {

    if(IsparkLib.isInternetConnected(InquiryMainActivity.this)){
        nameOfMethod();

        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(InquiryMainActivity.this);
        dialog.setTitle("Are you sure you want to update?");
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(InquiryMainActivity.this,InquiryMainActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
    }
    else{
        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(InquiryMainActivity.this);
        dialog.setTitle("Warning");
        dialog.setPositiveButton("OK",null);

        /*final TextView mes = new TextView(InquiryMainActivity.this);
        mes.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        mes.setText("Please check your internet connection");
        mes.setTextSize(20);*/  It's not necessary

        dialog.setMessage("Please check your internet connection");//

        dialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: thanks its working now but the problem is the Cancel doesn't show up. :/

Comment: @jajaja use this code `dialog.setCancelableOnTouchOutside(true);`

Comment: @jajaja what's the exact message you're getting from LOGCAT

Comment: Thanks I figured it out. it should be setNegativeButton() . Vote up for you! :)